# Flutter - convert Image widget to base64 or bytes

Tags: flutter, image, dart, file-upload

I wanted to know how I would convert the Image widget to base64 or bytes, because I took a clipping system and it delivers the result in Widget Image, I really need help to solve this problem.

I tried looking for Widget Image properties that could solve this, however, without success.
So I went looking for an answer on the internet and still I didn't find any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<int> imageBytes = await widget.readAsBytes();
print(imageBytes);
String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
```

This seems to work for me

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArImP.png

something like? it doesn't work, can you set up an example for me please using the conversion of the Image widget to base64?

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html

Comment: @UniversoVirtual I updated my answer to remove the fileData property as it should not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

this works also but try others also which work and easy for you

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

class ToImageData {
  static String imagetoData(String? imagepath) {
    final extension = path.extension(
      imagepath!.substring(imagepath.lastIndexOf("/")).replaceAll("/", ""),
    );
    final bytes = File(imagepath).readAsBytesSync();
    String base64 =
        "data:image/${extension.replaceAll(".", "")};base64,${base64Encode(bytes)}";
    return base64;
  }
}
```

to use is like this

```
ToImageData.imagetoData(fileImageSelected.path)
```

as per result would be a long string

something like

```
data:image/png;base64,UJYERWJKLDSJ1235612OLDSKHSJ
```